# nginx - proxy pass without redirection

Tags: nginx, proxy, rewrite

I have a website in AngularJS. Site uses hashbang mode and I am currently having a situation with prerendering.

My website has an URL like this:
`http://www.watchawearin.com/#!/item/511`
and I have a backend on URL: `http://www.watchawearin.com/api/`.

Now, when Facebook visits the URL above, it becomes: `http://www.watchawearin.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/item/511` which is okay, I have a config for that in nginx like this:

```
if ($prerender = 1) {
    rewrite .* /api/prerender break;
    proxy_pass $scheme://www.watchawearin.com;
}
```

Facebook fetches the prerendered page, but gets redirected to: `http://www.watchawearin.com/api/prerender/?_escaped_fragment_=%2Fitem%2F511`.

Can I achieve serving the prerendered page, but without the redirect?

Comment: This is just one of many reasons why "hashbang" should _never_ never **never** be used.

Comment: And how would it help, if I do not use hashbang?

Comment: The problem would not exist (nor would many others).

Comment: But I still need to proxy the request to API, if it comes from Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution:

```
if ($prerender = 1) {
    rewrite .* /api/ last;
}
```

and in /api/ I have a PHP framework backend, where I have a route matching `?_escaped_fragment_=/...` and I can do with it whatever I want.